# Alternative to .resize() for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage I am working on that utilizes a full screen image header at the top of the page. On mobile, there was an issue with the image resizing when the URL bar would disappear on scroll as the view-height would change, resulting in the image dimensions changing. I came across a variation of the code snippet included below which solved the problem perfectly, however it does not fix the problem on iOS Chrome app. I have discovered that the reason for this is because Chrome does not support this `.resize()` function. I am wondering if someone knew an alternative to this that is supported by chrome? I'll also include the HTML that is pertinent to this case.

HTML:

```
<div class="intro-bg">
            <div class="intro-bg-item"> 
                <div class="intro-bg-item-image" style="background-image: url(css/images/pb/home-banner.jpg)"></div><!-- /.intro-bg-item-image -->
            </div><!-- /.intro-bg-item -->

        </div><!-- /.intro-bg -->
```

jQuery:

```
var bg = $(".intro-bg-item-image, .intro-bg-item, .intro-bg, .caroufredsel_wrapper");

function resizeBackground() {
    bg.height( $(window).height() + 60);
}

$(window).resize(resizeBackground);
resizeBackground();
```

Comment: @razorsyntax this person is wondering how to resize the window. I am trying to figure out how to execute the function above on window resize in Chrome.

Comment: so listen for scroll also on mobile

Comment: Try use setInterval function - setInterval(function() { resizeBackground();}, 1000);

Comment: @epascarello perhaps I can just set the height to the view height on load and have it stay at that height. How might I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that the best way to solve this issue is to set the height on page load to the view height when viewing on a tablet or smaller device.

jQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
    var bg = $(".intro-bg-item-image, .intro-bg-item, .intro-bg, .caroufredsel_wrapper");
    function resizeBackground() {
        bg.height( $(window).height());
    }
    $(window).load(resizeBackground);
    resizeBackground();
}
```